# Returning a value from within a ForEach in Powershell

Tags: loops, powershell, foreach

This seems really basic, but I can't see how or why it behaves this way:

```
function ReturnStuff{
    $a=1,2,3,4,5
    $a.ForEach{
        return $_
    }
}

ReturnStuff
```

Why does this give me:
1
2
3
4
5
instead of just 1?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like you are calling `ForEach` (a function in `[System.Array]`) with a parameter which is a scriptblock. Essentially, you are defining and returning `{ Return $_ }` every iteration of the loop.

This means `ReturnStuff` will capture output each time, and because this function does nothing with the output of this line, all the output is returned:

```
$a.ForEach{ return $_ }
```

This behavior is similar to `$a | Foreach-Object { return $_ }`

So what to do?

1. Use a `ForEach` loop instead (not to be confused with `Foreach-Object`):

   ```
   ForEach ($item In $a) { return $item }
   ```
2. Select the first value returned from all the scriptblocks:

   ```
   $a.ForEach{ return $_ } | Select -First 1
   ```

Comment: Wow, that's one hell of a trap for newbies! Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't make any sense to me why they work differently.  Isn't the ForEach loop (option #1) also being called with a parameter which is a scriptblock?